# How to change the colour for missing value in geom_point of ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In default, the missing points are gray in geom_point of ggplot2. How could I change it to another colour?

These are codes to replicate my question.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, z = c(rep(1, 4), rep(NA, 2), rep(2, 4)))
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = factor(z))) + geom_point(size = 4)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = factor(z))) + geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_color_discrete(na.value="yellow")
```